# C++ preprocessor variable

Tags: c++, makefile, c-preprocessor

I'm using the `SKELETON_JAR` variable on my C++ code in one header. However, I want to allow the user to define the place of the jar in the compile time easily. I think the easiest way to do that is to put this define in makefile is that so?

```
#define SKELETON_JAR "./Util.jar"
```

Comment: What's your build environment?  Your OS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code:

```
#ifndef SKELETON_JAR
  #define SKELETON_JAR "./Util.jar" // default path
#endif
```

and then in the makefile use `CPPFLAGS:=-DSKELETON_JAR="./Util.jar"`.

Of course you have to make sure `CPPFLAGS` are passed to the compiler as part of the compile rule which is the case if you're using the default implicit rules.

[From GNU Make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

> Compiling C programs
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a command of the form `$(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)'

Comment: Useful bit of conditional compilation, though I would not have risked making any assumptions about the nature of the OP's makefile.  The important part is just the -D command line switch.

Comment: As an alternative to defining a default path you could also do something like this : 
#ifndef SKELETON_JAR
    #error "SKELETON_JAR hasn't been defined"
#endif

That way you'll easily catch any cases where it hasn't been defined in a Makefile

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your compiler, the normal way to do this is to use the compiler's -D flag in the makefile. For example:

MYFLAGS = -DSKELETON_JAR="foo"

then later on:

gcc $(MYFLAGS) $(OTHER_STUFF)

Comment: Some people just like to down-vote I guess.  I would perhaps have simply described the -D<macro>=<value> GCC option rather than make any possibly confusing assumptions about the OP's makefile.

Comment: the OP tagged the question with the `makefile` though

Comment: Not only did he tag it, he explicitly asked about makefile in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Use compilation flags for same and define flag in Makefile.